# Sprockets::Rails::Helper::AssetNotPrecompiled in Rails 4.2.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, sprockets, rails-sprockets

I'm currently working on a Rails `Rails 4.2.6` and `ruby 2.2.2p95`. I get the following error.[image]

Why are the assets not being precompile in development? I tried adding `gem 'sprockets-rails', '~> 3.0'` without success. I also tried in `development.rb` to change `config.assets.debug = true` to `false` but this didn't work either. The styles are in the assets folder, How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

In `config/environments/development.rb`, change the following

```
config.assets.debug = false
```

if it is true.

Answer (score 0):

Little correction. use `assets` instead of `assest`

```
config.assets.debug = false
```